# Display product custom options on category page in Magento 2

Tags: magento

Display custom options on product category page and also change the price according to options change. So user can easily select option from category page and addtocart.

Answer (score 0):

**Put the code in category page in product collection**

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product); ?>
<?php 
    foreach($customOptions as $option) {
        $values = $option->getValues();
        if (empty($values)) { 
            continue;
        }
        ?>
  <div class="cusome-option">
      <?php foreach($values as $value) :  ?>
        <span><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></span>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

custome option willl show on dropdown , select , multiselect , etc...